# How to disable the "hide all windows" button on the top right of Gnome

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

After upgrading my desktop to Debian 11 (from 10), Gnome (3.38) has an invisible button on the top right that hides all windows. How can I disable that?

Comment: From memory it's in settings>office and it's called **hot corners** or maybe in gnome settings.

Comment: @lejurassien I don't think so. There's no such thing as "Settings, Office". There's Tweaks, Top Bar, but it only has an "Activites Overview Hot Corner" there.

Comment: Ok go in  terminal and tape

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell enable-hot-corners false`
                                                                                                                           for re-enable

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell enable-hot-corners true`

Comment: Otherwise there are extensions you can install tweaks>extensions 
which can be found at https://extensions.gnome.org
which are installed with firefox

Comment: No such key “enable-hot-corners”